# The existence of a strange function on $[0,1]^2$

Tags: analysis, functions

Does such a function $f:[0,1]^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ exist:

1. $f(\cdot,y)$ and $f(x,\cdot)$ are continuous functions with respect to "$\cdot$", for any $x,y\in[0,1]$;
2. The zero set of $f$ is dense in $[0,1]^2$;
3. $f$ is not identically zero.

Any help, any hint, any reference will be appreciated.

Comment: I think 2D condition does not influence result, so one can consider 1D case.

Comment: No, the 2D case is significantly harder.